# Fire Ajax Rest call only for elements in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, rest

i've got the following problem.

We're using a template which generates a list of divs, all with the same classes etc. 
Each div contains a hidden input field containing the ID of the target site it links to.

Now my job is to use this ID to generate ajax rest calls for each of the divs to receive the amount of comments on the target site.

My current solution is a simple jQuery each, iterating through all divs and firing a rest call for each div containing the individual target ID and then appending the number of comments on the target page.

However, there might be a huge amount of divs on the page, so the customer only wants the rest calls of the currently viewable divs fired while scrolling down the page.

Is there any way to do this?

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION: i have to use jQuery 1.7 and it has to work in IE8! -.-**

kind regards

Additional info:
All divs that are rendered by the template are visible, so i can't check for :visible. I need a way to check if they are in the viewport. I tried some inview-plugins etc., but they need a specific ID they are tied to, and then check if the element with this ID comes into view. However, all my elements have the same class and no ID at all as they are rendered by the same template.

Comment: Have a look at scroll event, only make the ajax call when div is in the range.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `$('.element').is(":visible")`

**http://jsfiddle.net/4mu18z2y/1/**

I haven't tested it in IE8 though.

Comment: All divs that are rendered by the template are visible, so i can't check for :visible. I need a way to check if they are in the viewport. i tried some inview-plugins etc but they need a specific ID they are tied to and then check if the element with this ID comes into view. however, all my elements have the same class as they are rendered by the same template.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the window position and the offset top of each element...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowSize = $(window).height();
    console.log("Window size: " + windowSize);
    $(".test").each(function(){
        var top = $(this).offset().top; // element top position
        if(top < windowSize){
            console.log($(this));
            // your ajax call
        }
    });
});
```

Finddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2wnbp2c/

Comment: Huum... This should be coused by how you are positioning your elements... Make a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ and let take a look at your code...