# jquery-visible plugin: Using `element.visible(true)` - but still returns true only when the "entire" element is visible. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, visible

**[JsFiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/w7eowzcq/36/)**

From [this article](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery),

> In its simplest form, the element can be checked as follows:
>
> ```
> $('#element').visible()
> ```
>
> This method will return true if the entire element is visible (I.e.,
>   it will return false if any part of that element is outside the
>   viewport. Passing true to the 'visible' method, will tell the plugin
>   to return true if ANY part of the element is visible on the users
>   screen.
>
> ```
> $('#element').visible( true )
> ```

**In the following script, the `if` block `if ( $('.firstPage').visible(true) ) ...` is expected to be executed as soon as *a part of* the `.firstPage` `div` becomes visible on the screen while scrolling.**

**But the problem is that it does not get executed (which implies that `$('.firstPage').visible(true)` does not return true) as long as the ENTIRE `.firstPage` element becomes visible. Why? What am I missing?**

---

***CODE:***

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){

var lastScrollTop = 0;
var originalHeaderPosition =  $(".header-menu-container-nav").offset().top;

var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var vph = $(window).height();

var currentHeaderPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
var deltaHeaderPosition = currentHeaderPosition - originalHeaderPosition;

if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){ // downscroll code
    if (deltaHeaderPosition >= vph) {
        $('.header-menu-container-nav').addClass('sticky');
        $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeIn();
    }
} else {// upscroll code
    if ($('.firstPage').visible( true )) {
        $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeOut(function() {
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').attr('style','');
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').removeClass('sticky');
        });
    }
}
   lastScrollTop = scrollTop;

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible/issues

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you are resetting `lastScrollTop = 0;` *inside* the scroll event. The test `scrollTop > lastScrollTop` will *always* be true (except when you go back to the extreme top - position 0).

Once you fix that the next issue is multiple `fadeIn`s occuring. You need to animate the opacity to `1` instead of using fadeIn. Using animate means you cannot rely on the completion event firing, so I switched it to use the jQuery animation queue `promise` and `always` to ensure the next code is run.

Here is what I have come up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w7eowzcq/64/

I am not 100% certain of the desired behaviour, but this should help.

```
/**
 * Function for the header's drama!
 **/
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var originalHeaderPosition = $(".header-menu-container-nav").offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {

    //alert("OriginalHeaderPosition: "+originalHeaderPosition); //check

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var vph = $(window).height();
    //alert("Viewport Height:"+vph+"\nDocument Height:" + $(document).height()); //check

    var currentHeaderPosition = $(document).scrollTop(); //this is same as scrollTop. Fix them later
    var deltaHeaderPosition = currentHeaderPosition - originalHeaderPosition;
    console.log("deltaHeaderPosition: " + deltaHeaderPosition);

    if (scrollTop >= lastScrollTop) { // downscroll code
        if (deltaHeaderPosition >= vph) {
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').addClass('sticky');
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
        }
    } else { // upscroll code
        if ($('.firstPage').visible(true)) {
            console.log("visible");
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').animate({
                opacity: 0
            }).promise().always(function () {
                $('.header-menu-container-nav').attr('style', '');
                $('.header-menu-container-nav').removeClass('sticky');
            });
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```