# Changing color when specific div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please tell me how can I make this in the most right way.

HTML:

```
<div id="fixed-red" class="fixed-red"></div>
<div id="fixed-green" class="fixed-green"></div>
<div id="fixed-blue" class="fixed-blue"></div>
<div id="red" class="red"></div>
<div id="green" class="green"></div>
<div id="blue" class="blue"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.fixed-red,.fixed-green,.fixed-blue{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  position:fixed;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  background:#333;
}
.fixed-green{
  top:50px;
}
.fixed-blue{
  top:90px;
}
.red-active{
  background:#f00;
}
.green-active{
  background:#0f0;
}
.blue-active{
  background:#00f;
}
.red,.green,.blue{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.red{
  background:#900;
}
.green{
  background:#090;
}
.blue{
  background:#009;
}
```

I want to add/remove `red/green/blue-active` class to the `fixed-red/green/blue` divs when the user is on/off the `red`, `green`, or `blue` divs(when they are visible), so the small divs would be respectively highlighted with the color of the big, display divs when the user is on them.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought of adding event `on`, on the `red`, `green`, and `blue` big divs, but I don't know how to check if they are visible

Comment: For modern browsers, see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had to tweak the code a little so the code could be more D.R.Y.
The classes are now replaced by `color` class.

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('.color').each(function() {
      var activeColor = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).addClass(activeColor + '-active');
    } else {
      $('#fixed-' + activeColor).removeClass(activeColor + '-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.fixed-red,
.fixed-green,
.fixed-blue {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.fixed-green {
  top: 50px;
}

.fixed-blue {
  top: 90px;
}

.red-active {
  background: #f00;
}

.green-active {
  background: #0f0;
}

.blue-active {
  background: #00f;
}

.color {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#red {
  background: #900;
}

#green {
  background: #090;
}

#blue {
  background: #009;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed-red" class="fixed-red red-active"></div>
<div id="fixed-green" class="fixed-green"></div>
<div id="fixed-blue" class="fixed-blue"></div>
<div id="red" class="color"></div>
<div id="green" class="color"></div>
<div id="blue" class="color"></div>
```

Here is a working fiddle of that

https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/ds9x55z7/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I doubt people use `hover` for this kind of things

Comment: I guess you can use `mouseenter mouseleave` events. U can see a sample of that https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/ds9x55z7/1/ (But that is indeed the hover function)

Comment: Thanks, but again, I don't think this is done this way(using mouse). I can think of `scrollTop`, to check  the height of the elements, but not sure if this is right approach and how to make this

Comment: I think you might be referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33979503/4374566

Comment: If I were to borrow some code, your case might look like https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/ds9x55z7/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Boy with silver wings!

Comment: Happy to Help @user7362793 :)