# Change background color circle based on what is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change the color of my visual navigation, based on what "productcard" is visible in screen. It looks like this on my webpage (only on tablet and mobile):

[image]

Is there a way with javascript to make the 2nd, 3rd of 4th circle the darker grey based on what product is in viewport?

My markup right now is:

```css
  .usp-radio {
   display: none!important;
  }
  .usp-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: normal;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   overflow-x: auto;
   scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  }
   .usp-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
 }  
  .usp-item {
   flex: 0 0 auto;
   max-width: none!important;
   width: 100%;
   scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
  .usp-text {
   max-width: 260px;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  #usp-1-button:checked ~ .usp-container .usp-item {
   transform: translateX(0%);
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #usp-2-button:checked ~ .usp-container .usp-item {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #usp-3-button:checked ~ .usp-container .usp-item {
   transform: translateX(-200%);
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  #usp-4-button:checked ~ .usp-container .usp-item {
   transform: translateX(-300%);
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .content-container.usp-flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  .usp-radio + label {
   background-color: #C5C5C5;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   order: 2;
   margin: 0px 2.5px;
  }
   .usp-radio:checked + label {
   background-color: #707070;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content-container usp-flex">
  <input type="radio" id="usp-1-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide" checked/>
  <label for="usp-1-button"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="usp-2-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide"/>
  <label for="usp-2-button"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="usp-3-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide"/>
  <label id="usp-3-label" for="usp-3-button"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="usp-4-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide"/>
  <label id="usp-4-label" for="usp-4-button"></label>
 <div class="usp-container" style="order: 1;">
  <div id="usp-1" class="usp-item">
   <div><img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-door.jpg" width="52" height="52"/></div>
   <div style="margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;"><span class="usp-title">Uniek kijkje achter de schermen</span></div>
   <div><span class="usp-text">Doe mee aan een panelsessie en krijg direct een kijkje achter de schermen.</span></div>
  </div>
   <div id="usp-2" class="usp-item">
   <div><img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-feedback.jpg" width="52" height="52"/></div>
   <div style="margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;"><span class="usp-title">Vertel ons over jouw ideale website</span></div>
   <div><span class="usp-text">Geef aan wat voor u belangrijk is en misschien ziet u uw ideeën later terug!</span></div>
  </div>
   <div id="usp-3" class="usp-item">
   <div><img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-reiskosten.jpg" width="52" height="52"/></div>
   <div style="margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;"><span class="usp-title">Reiskosten worden vergoed</span></div>
   <div><span class="usp-text">Komt u bij ons langs op kantoor? Dan vergoeden wij uw reiskosten.</span></div>
  </div>
   <div id="usp-4" class="usp-item">
   <div><img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-hotel.jpg" width="52" height="52"/></div>
   <div style="margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;"><span class="usp-title">Maak kans op een GRATIS verblijf</span></div>
   <div><span class="usp-text">Neemt u deel aan ons gebruikerspanel? Dan maakt u kans op een gratis uitje!</span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So it updates when I use the navigation, but I also need it to update when the card is swiped to the left. I saw something that might work in this thread:

[Changing color when specific div is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416863/changing-color-when-specific-div-is-visible/41417072)

However that works for vertical offset/scrolling, not horizontal.

Comment: How does the swiping work? Please also share the JavaScript code.

Comment: The swiping is already in there. It is done with overflow-x: auto and flex: 0 0 auto on the children. The problem is: i have no idea where to start with my JS code on this. My JS knowledge is kind of basic.

Comment: Ah, I just saw the `scroll-snap-type` CSS property.

Comment: was my answer able to help you? Do you have more specific questions? I will add comments to the JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you! To be honest, after searching for a while and reading your comment ( which does work) I concluded it was too much a hassle and removed swiping. Only using next + previous buttons now. Thanks for your answer though, it was what I asked!

Comment: Good to hear! If your question has been answered, please consider also marking my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience carousels usually rely solely on the transform property and don't really use the scroll offset [[1]](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) [[2]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) [[3]](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). They use ["Touch Events"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and sometimes the ["Drag and Drop API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) to work across all devices and platforms.

However, out of curiosity I adapted your snippet to use the scroll snapping and scroll offset.
Note, that the `Element.scrollTo()` method is [not compatible with every browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo#Browser_Compatibility) and might need [a polyfill](http://iamdustan.com/smoothscroll/).

Next, the `onScroll` function relies on a modulus calculation using `scrollLeft` property. This might lead to some errors or inaccuracies on [systems using display scaling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft).

Finally, this snippet uses a passive scroll event for performance reasons. You might want to [test if this is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Safely_detecting_option_support).

*Note: You can try out the snippet by scrolling horizontally pressing the shift key.*

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.usp-container')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="usp-slide"]')

/**
 * This listener calculates the modulo of the scroll position by the visible width.
 * Every time the result equals 0, the scroll position is exactly an integer multiple of the width.
 * This means that the carousel has reached another page.
 * The scroll-snap-type property makes sure that the container snaps perfectly to integer multiple.
 */
const onScroll = function () {

    if (container.scrollLeft % container.offsetWidth === 0) {
        const page = container.scrollLeft / container.offsetWidth                   // the multiples range between 0-3
        const radio = document.getElementById(`usp-${page + 1}-button`)    // radio buttons are numbered 1-4
        radio.click()
    }
}

/**
 * Determine the target page by an HTML data attribute on the radio button.
 * Scroll to the desired position.
 * 
 * @param {MouseEvent} event: Click event used to determine the target/clicked element
 */
const onClick = function (event) {

    const button = event.target
    const targetPage = button.dataset.target

    container.scrollTo({
        left:     targetPage * container.offsetWidth,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    })
}

container.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, {
    passive: true
})

for (const button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', onClick)
}
```

```css
.usp-radio {
  display: none!important;
}

.usp-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: normal;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.usp-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.usp-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: none!important;
  width: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.usp-title,
.usp-text {
  max-width: 260px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-container.usp-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.usp-radio+label {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  order: 2;
  margin: 0px 2.5px;
}

.usp-radio:checked+label {
  background-color: #707070;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container usp-flex">
  <input type="radio" id="usp-1-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide" checked data-target="0" />
  <label for="usp-1-button"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="usp-2-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide" data-target="1" />
  <label for="usp-2-button"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="usp-3-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide" data-target="2" />
  <label id="usp-3-label" for="usp-3-button"></label>

  <input type="radio" id="usp-4-button" class="usp-radio" name="usp-slide" data-target="3" />
  <label id="usp-4-label" for="usp-4-button"></label>

  <div class="usp-container" style="order: 1;">
    <div id="usp-1" class="usp-item">
      <img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-door.jpg" width="52" height="52" />
      <span class="usp-title">Uniek kijkje achter de schermen</span>
      <span class="usp-text">Doe mee aan een panelsessie en krijg direct een kijkje achter de schermen.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="usp-2" class="usp-item">
      <img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-feedback.jpg" width="52" height="52" />
      <span class="usp-title">Vertel ons over jouw ideale website</span>
      <span class="usp-text">Geef aan wat voor u belangrijk is en misschien ziet u uw ideeën later terug!</span>
    </div>
    <div id="usp-3" class="usp-item">
      <img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-reiskosten.jpg" width="52" height="52" />
      <span class="usp-title">Reiskosten worden vergoed</span>
      <span class="usp-text">Komt u bij ons langs op kantoor? Dan vergoeden wij uw reiskosten.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="usp-4" class="usp-item">
      <img src="https://www.voordeeluitjes.nl/Images/freeValues/userpanel-hotel.jpg" width="52" height="52" />
      <span class="usp-title">Maak kans op een GRATIS verblijf</span>
      <span class="usp-text">Neemt u deel aan ons gebruikerspanel? Dan maakt u kans op een gratis uitje!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```