# Run function() if appear in viewport ? jquery-viewport-checker

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I use [anime-js](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime) for create an animation. But, It is far in the page. I would like to launch my animation function when the section in which the item to be animated appears on the screen.

I tried a plugin that I like to use ([jquery viewportchecker](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker)) but it does not seem to do that.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicated question, Please see this post (Jquery check if element is visible in viewport

) {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport}

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. The problem with your method is that the function repeats itself to infinity.

I create a little function for check if element is visible. With that, no plugin needed.

```
function checkVisible( elm, evale ) {
    var evale;
    evale = evale || "object visible";
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
        scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
        y = $(elm).offset().top,
        elementHeight = $(elm).height();

    if (evale == "object visible") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)) && (y > (scrolltop - elementHeight)));
    if (evale == "above") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)));
}
```

I also created a variable `var counter = 0;`. And as soon as the function is called, I increment by 1.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    if (counter == 0){
        if (checkVisible($('.frontend'))) {
           // Your function here
         }
       }
     }
```

At the first time the function will be called, counter will be 1, and thus, the function will not repeat. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JQuery's on load method?

Something like

`$(document).on('load', '.exampleClass', function() { //do stuff } )`

Comment: This is not wroking

Comment: please post your codeslike this.read this
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery.appear

This plugin implements custom appear/disappear events which are fired when an element became visible/invisible in the browser viewport.

https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

```
$('someselector').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
});
$('someselector').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
  // this element is now outside browser viewport
});
```

Also this plugin provides custom jQuery filter for manual checking element appearance.

```
$('someselector').is(':appeared')
```