# Check if element with class is visible in viewport

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if a class is currently visible in the viewport. I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979503/609630) (can't get a reply to my question). The original post used ID's instead of classes, I've changed it to detect a class called `.white-section` which is repeated down the page.

At the moment it only detects the first `.white-section`, how can I get it to detect them all as they come and go into the viewport?

```
$('#content').scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(".white-section").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(".white-section").offset().top + $(".white-section").outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
         $('.header-container').addClass('.alt-menu');
    }
    else {
        $('.header-container').removeClass('.alt-menu');
    }
});
```

This is how the html is setup:

```
<div class="header-container"></div>

<div class="white-section"></div>
<div class="white-section"></div>
<div class="white-section"></div>
<div class="white-section"></div>
<div class="white-section"></div>
```

Comment: How do the white-section relate to the header-container?  My initial thought is this is going to involve an each over the white-sections.

Comment: @Taplar Sorry I should've been clear on that bit. When I scroll onto a white section, it adds a class to the header container and removes it when it's not on a white section

Comment: So the header-container is a child of the white-section?

Comment: Look at [this plugin](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible). Here is a [demo](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html)

Comment: @Taplar Just updated the question. No it's outside of the white section. To explain it a bit better, I have a white menu which gets lost on a white section so I want to reverse the colours when on it. Then revert back to normal when on a non white section.

Comment: So is there only one header-container on the page?

Comment: @Taplar Yes one header container but multiple white sections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the following a try.  It loops over the elements to try to find any that match your conditional and if any do, it adds the class.  I also added some slight throttling to the solution and also cached the lookups so that the scroll event will be faster.

```js
(function($) {
  var scrollingIsThrottled = false;
  var $allWhiteSections = $(".white-section");
  var $window = $(window);
  var $headerContainer = $('.header-container');

  $('#content').scroll(function() {
    if (!scrollingIsThrottled) {
      scrollingIsThrottled = true;

      var $whiteSpaceMatchingExpression = $allWhiteSections.filter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var top_of_element = $this.offset().top;
        var bottom_of_element = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_screen = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
        var top_of_screen = $window.scrollTop();

        return ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element));
      });
      
      if ($whiteSpaceMatchingExpression.length) {
        $headerContainer.addClass('alt-menu');
      } else {
        $headerContainer.removeClass('alt-menu');
      }
      
      scrollingIsThrottled = false;
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```