# How to detect an element is in the end of the page?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating my custom tag helper and I don't know what is this technique called?

My `contenteditable` is always in the bottom of the page, whenever I press `@` character, it will show a custom dropdown menu at the bottom. Then, to use the menu, I have to scroll the page.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Now, I want to detect if there is no more height in the bottom, it will be shown at the top of the `contenteditable`.

Can you give me some google search keywords to understand about it? Or maybe it's better if I have a small demo.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe useful https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport

Comment: @GhitaB ya, thanks! I think it's different from mine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c3j451Lt/6/ but you are right... you can't use this because I understand your dropdown is always out of the viewport. I suggest you can position it always in the viewport so the scroll to be not needed. You can keep the @ and input where it is now, but the list with suggestion to be above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a DEMO below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var container_height = $("#container").height();
 var first_position = container_height - $("#first").position().top;
  var second_position = container_height - $("#second").position().top;
  var last_position = container_height - $("#last").position().top;
  
  console.log(`First position: ${first_position}`)
  console.log(`Second position: ${second_position}`)
  console.log(`Last position: ${last_position}`)
})
```

```css
#first, #second, #last {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first {
  background: #556622;
}

#second {
  background: #773399;
}

#last {
  background: #996677;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">FIRST</div>
  <div id="second">SECOND</div>
  <div id="last">LAST</div>
</div>
```

You can calculate the distance from the end of your container to the element by calculating: container's height - the top position of your element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var container_height = $("#container").height();
  var first_position = container_height - $("#first").position().top;
  var second_position = container_height - $("#second").position().top;
  var last_position = container_height - $("#last").position().top;
  console.log(first_position, second_position, last_position);
});
```

Example of html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">FIRST</div>
  <div id="second">SECOND</div>
  <div id="last">LAST</div>
</div>
```

Some css for nice styles:

```
#first, #second, #last {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first {
  background: #556622;
}

#second {
  background: #773399;
}

#last {
  background: #996677;
}
```

So, when this distance is less than 100px (let's say) you will change from your A to B case.

Comment: Thanks! I will try