# How to run the script of a website at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website and the footer has a JavaScript code.

I want my JavaScript code to run only if the user open scroll down to that part of the website.

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: I didn't think I'd ever ask that on a question tagged with JS but...how is that related to `C`?

Comment: it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport

Comment: i tried to delay it but i will not work because i dont know when a specific user will scroll up that part of my site.

Comment: The `window.scroll` event combined with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your code when footer is `.visible(true)`.

something like this:

```
if ($('#footer').visible(true)) {
    // The element is visible, do something
} else {
    // The element is NOT visible, do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may separate your js code in file and when user scroll down append that to your footer section like below.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           var YourScript= document.createElement('script');
            YourScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            YourScript.src = 'js source path may be cdn ........';
            document.getElementById('Your-Footer-Div-ID').appendChild(YourScript);
       }
 });
```