# Start counter with a little delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I reload my website a counter is running. I want to delay this a little like when the user opens a website and scrolls down and then the counter starts running.

```js
$('.counter, .counterplus').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">
  <div class="allcount">
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">0</div>
    <p>Customer support</p>
  </div>
  <div class="allcount">
    <div class="counterplus" data-count="115">0</div>
    <p>Happy Customers</p>
  </div>
  <div class="allcount">
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">0</div>
    <p>Client Satisfaction</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a random delay or do you want the counter to start when it's visible in the page?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to start the counter on scroll down? or after a certain delay?.. for delay you can use setTimeout

Comment: when user scroll down this section is come then counter happen

Comment: Try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791374/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-in-viewport

Comment: yes i need counter start when scroll down

Comment: In which case the code you need to do that is in the linked question, specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979503/519413). You just need to combine it with the counter logic above.