# How can I make the pixel value of the height in my code dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I've built a small script to let chosen objects fade in when the user scrolls down. My problem is that this script is pretty static. If I applied this on 20 different objects, say, I would have to set the height every time. Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $(".header-js-scroll-fade").css({"opacity" : "1"});
      $(".home-vorteile").addClass("header-img-fade-in-by-scroll");
    }
    else {
      $(".header-js-scroll-fade").css({"opacity" : "0"});
      $(".home-vorteile").removeClass("header-img-fade-in-by-scroll");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header-js-scroll-fade {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="vorteile-text">Vertrauen durch,</h1>

<section class="home-vorteile">
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade header-img-fade-in-by-scroll">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Sicherheit.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade header-img-fade-in-by-scroll">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Neueste KI Technik.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade header-img-fade-in-by-scroll">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Beste Materialien.</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have fixed your snippet, if you agree please approve it.

Comment: @NoNickAvailable yes thats my intention. I'm sorry for my bad explaining. This is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks if the element is visible by the user, if so it adds the class, if not it removes it. To make this happend you just need to apply the `class header-js-scroll-fade` to any element you want.

The function isInViewport is from the User Tom Pažourek, found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658647/8605830

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658647/8605830
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(document).ready(function () {

  $(window).scroll(function () {
  
    $('.header-js-scroll-fade').each(function () {
      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        $(this).addClass("visible");
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass("visible");
      }
      
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.header-js-scroll-fade {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.header-js-scroll-fade.visible {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="vorteile-text">Vertrauen durch,</h1>

<section class="home-vorteile">
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Sicherheit.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Neueste KI Technik.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="header-js-scroll-fade">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
    <h2>Beste Materialien.</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tested the Code in Edge,Chrome and Firefox. The only one where it perfectly worked was Edge. In Firefox and chrome does the effect work but only if i scroll from the bottom to top.

Comment: What version of the browsers are you running? Because I tested in Firefox and Chrome where it worked perfectly. There should be no problem because all new browsers are using an adapted version of the Webkit engine.