# jQuery focus is causing scroll to bottom

Tags: jquery

I literally just comment out this line and the page loads without scrolling to the bottom:

```
jQuery(map_input).appendTo(container);

jQuery(map_input).focus();
```

Am I missing something? The field does focus but the page loads and scrolls to the bottom.

Edit: I'm using jQuery 1.4.4

The input field is above the fold, although I'm loading the input field after the page is loaded

Comment: Isn't this the expected action if you focus an input that isn't in view? Where is `#input-search-by-zip` located on your page?

Comment: It's above the fold, but I'm loading a map and then appending an input to it, see my edit

Comment: It's happening to move the focused element into the viewport. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898203/jquery-focus-without-scroll