# Focus div without jumping to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to focus an element (a slider/carousel) upon page load, to allow immediate control of the slider using arrow keys. JQuery's `.focus()` works, but automatically scrolls the element into view. This is a problem on limited viewports, where the top of the page is unexpectedly scrolled past.

Is it possible to focus an element without jumping to it?

Comment: What slider/carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4898203/1529061. Use `scrollTo` to restore scrolling position.

Comment: @WesFoster I'm using Flickity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just restoring scroll position will work

```js
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#your-element').focus()
$(window).scrollTop(position);
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/duwafa/1/)